# Mini DC motor will not function with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have tried setting my motor up using this example: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-spin-a-dc-motor-with-the-arduino.html

But the motor will not work – it is not broken, it works if I attach it directly to a battery. 
I do however hear a extremely vague clicking sound from the motor.

Any suggestions on what is wrong, and how to fix it? Am I missing something obvious?

The motor name is: H30480 MOT4, Mini DC motor - 7,2Vdc / 500mA 16200rpm

This is the code:

```
int motorPin = 9;
void setup() {

 pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
 digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
 delay(1000); 
 digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
 delay(1000);

}
```

And here is my setup:

[image: setup arduino and motor]

[image: close up of wires]

Im quite new to Arduino, so suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wonder if I need to describe the rpm somehow?

Comment: I'm sure you'll get much better help on the Arduino site than here.

Comment: Thanks, I have now posted the question there too.

Comment: OK - please don't cross-post though - you should delete the question here now that it's on the Arduino StackExchange.

Comment: @PaulR Deleted the one on Arduino StackEchange instead since there was a reply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code seems ok. Although i see that you power your arduino via USB. The computer limits the current to 500mA but about 50 - 80mA goes to the Arduino itself. So you get about 450 - 420 mA for your DC motor that is not enough. If you use external power for your Arduino you will probably be able to properly power the motor via the Arduino but 500mA is still a lot of current.

The best solution is to externally power the DC motor.

Comment: aha! So if I add a 9v battery to the circuit you think it will work?

Comment: Make sure to provide enought current. Look at the motor specs. At no load it needs 0.5A, at max load it need 3.29A

Comment: I think you need a power supply of ~4000mA and 3 - 9V to properly power the motor. The battery wont be enough